# How to add AD Group to SharePoint Group using Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, active-directory, groups

I want to create a SharePoint Group named "SomeGroup" and then want to add crossponding Active Directory Group to this SharePoint Group "SomeGroup". I have searched but not found any good example to accomplish this using powershell. What will be the Poweshell script for this for sharepoint 2013

Comment: How to add AD group. From Santosh does not work ..

Comment: For what is this command ?? I don't understand. I wish to add ad group to sp group. But code from Santosh does not work. With this code I can add users but not group. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$SiteCollection = "http://site/sitecollection"
$ADGroupName = "domain\adgroup"
$SPGroupName = "My Test Group A1"
$SPGroupDescription = "Test Group A1’s Description"
$SPGroupPermission = "Read"

#Start of script
$site = Get-SPWeb $SiteCollection

#Check if the group already exists
if ($site.SiteGroups[$SPGroupName] -eq $null)
{

#Ensure Group/User is part of site collection users beforehand and add them if needed
$site.EnsureUser($ADGroupName)

# Get the AD Group/User in a format that PowerShell can use otherwise there will be a string error
$ADGroupSPFriendly = $site | Get-SPUser $ADGroupName

#Create the SharePoint Group – Group Name, Group Owner, Group Member, Group Description. Can’t add AD group yet…
$NewSPGroup = $site.SiteGroups.Add($SPGroupName, $site.CurrentUser, $site.CurrentUser, $SPGroupDescription)
$site.AssociatedGroups.Add($site.SiteGroups[$SPGroupName]);
$NewSPAccount = $site.SiteGroups[$SPGroupName]

#Assign the Group permission
$GroupAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($NewSPAccount)
$GroupRole = $site.RoleDefinitions[$SPGroupPermission]
$GroupAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($GroupRole)
$site.RoleAssignments.Add($GroupAssignment)

#Add the AD Group/User to the group, can’t be done during group creation when using Powershell otherwise errors so is done now.
Set-SPUser -Identity $ADGroupSPFriendly -Web $SiteCollection -Group $SPGroupName
}
$site.Dispose()
}
```

Surce: http://blog.thefullcircle.com/2013/02/create-a-sharepoint-group-with-permissions-and-add-an-ad-group-to-it/

Comment: The last Line: Set-SPUser -Identity $ADGroupSPFriendly -Web $SiteCollection -Group $SPGroupName will add a single/one user to the SPGroup, right ? But I want to add whole the AD Group to SP Group, How that will be accomplish?

Comment: It should add the AD group. Give it a try and see what happens

Comment: I have tested. It did not add AD group, Error: a valid user name or object is required??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which i have modified little bit for adding Ad group in to share point group for a site collection

```
Function AddADGroup($SPGroupName,$ADGroupName)
{    
    $SiteCollection = "http://yoursitcollectionurl"
    $site = Get-SPWeb $SiteCollection
    $site.EnsureUser($ADGroupName)
    $ADGroupSPFriendly = $site | Get-SPUser $ADGroupName
    Set-SPUser -Identity $ADGroupSPFriendly -Web $SiteCollection -Group $SPGroupName
    Write-Host $ADGroupName
    Write-Host $ADGroupSPFriendly
    Write-Host "Added the ADGroup" + $ADGroupName + "Sucessfully to the SPGroup" + $SPGroupName

    $site.Dispose()
}

#To Execute this function 

AddADGroup "Sharepointgroup" "Domain\ADGroup"
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified and shorter version

```
function updateWebGroup ($web, $spGroupName, $adGroupName){
    $group = $web.AssociatedGroups | ? {$_.Name -eq $spGroupName}
    if($group)
    {
        $adGroup = $web.EnsureUser($adGroupName)
        $group.AddUser($adGroup)
        $group.Update()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution for this using pnp-powershell.

```
$context = Connect-PnPonline -Url [mysite] -ReturnConnection
$web = Get-PnPWeb -Connection $context
$adgroup = "c:0t.c|tenant|[ad id]"    
$ensureUser = $web.EnsureUser($adgroup)
$adgroup= Get-PnPUser $adgroup -Connection $context
Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName $adgroup.LoginName -Identity "$($web.Title) Owners" -Connection $context
```

- To find the AD group ID in Sharepoint, add that group to some sp user group, and then grab the ID shown when you click on that entity.
- Change "$($web.Title) Owners" to whatever group that already exist in the site

Answer (score -2):

The correct command is -

```
New-SPUser -UserAlias "domain\username" -Web $WebUrl -Group $SharePointGroupName
```