# Add AD group to Sharepoint 2013 using powershell as the AD group domain and name is changed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, groups

Currently SP 2013 site has domain1\abc AD group but this has to be updated/add new group domain2\xyz using powershell for 500 site collections. will the identity claim be generated if the group is created from powershell.

Comment: Your question is poorly formulated, but let me see if I got it: You want to copy a AD group from a different domain? Or you want to add a new ad group to domain1\abc?

Comment: Currently I have old and new  AD groups and users are also migrated from old to new group (where domain and name are changed). Now the SP site has old AD group, how can I add new AD group using powershell for about 100 sites

Comment: is this similar to what you need? http://tharindupg.blogspot.com.br/2015/01/change-active-directory-of-sharepoint.html

Comment: No Rafael, I need powershell script  to add the newly created AD group to SharePoint 2013 SP group in 100 sites..later I can run the PS script to remove old AD group

Comment: ok, so this new group is already synced with sharepoint? when you are adding permissions you can pull it? what kind of permission you want to give to this group in the 100 sites?

Comment: I don't have to sync with SP group, the new AD group (domain2\xyz) has set os users whose domain is updated to doamin2.May be you can let me know the script to add this domain2\xyz group under Members SP group for abt 100 sites.

Comment: check my answer bellow. the script will run trough all your site collection and add the specified group to them

Answer (score 0):

See if this script works out for you

```
   function AddAccountToAllSites ($siteURL, $accountName, $permLevel, [switch]$skipRootSite, $newGroupDescription)
    {
        #Get Site Collection
        $site = Get-SPSite $siteURL

        #Check if the accountName variable contains a slash - if so, it is an AD account
        #If not, it is a SharePoint Group
        $rootWeb = $site.RootWeb
        if ($accountName.Contains("\")) { $account = $rootWeb.EnsureUser($accountName) }
        else {
            #If the SharePoint Group does not exist, create it with the name and description specified
            if (!$rootWeb.SiteGroups[$accountName])
            {
                $rootWeb.SiteGroups.Add($accountName, $rootWeb.CurrentUser, $rootWeb.CurrentUser, $newGroupDescription)
            }
            $account = $rootWeb.SiteGroups[$accountName]
        }
        $rootWeb.Dispose()

        #Step through each site in the site collection
        $site | Get-SPWeb -limit all | ForEach-Object {

            #Check if the user has chosen to skip the root site - if so, do not change permissions on it
            if (($skipRootSite) -and ($site.Url -eq $_.Url)) { write-host "Root site" $_.Url "will be bypassed" }
            else {
                #Check if the current site is inheriting permissions from its parent
                #If not, set permissions on current site
                if ($_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) {

                    $assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($account)
                    $role = $_.RoleDefinitions[$permLevel]
                    $assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role)
                    $_.RoleAssignments.Add($assignment)

                    write-host "Account" $accountName "added to site" $_.Url "with" $permLevel "permissions."
                }
                else {
                    write-host "Site" $_.Url "will not be modified as it inherits permissions from a parent site."
                }
            }
        }
        #Display completion message and dispose of site object
        write-host "Operation Complete."
        $site.Dispose()
    }
```

[Source](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/02/add-sharepoint-or-ad-groupuser-to-all.html)

here is what you asked secondly

```
$SiteCollection = "http://site/sitecollection"
$ADGroupName = "domain\adgroup"
$SPGroupName = "My Test Group A1"
$SPGroupDescription = "Test Group A1’s Description"
$SPGroupPermission = "Read"

#Start of script
$site = Get-SPWeb $SiteCollection

#Check if the group already exists
if ($site.SiteGroups[$SPGroupName] -eq $null)
{

#Ensure Group/User is part of site collection users beforehand and add them if needed
$site.EnsureUser($ADGroupName)

# Get the AD Group/User in a format that PowerShell can use otherwise there will be a string error
$ADGroupSPFriendly = $site | Get-SPUser $ADGroupName

#Create the SharePoint Group – Group Name, Group Owner, Group Member, Group Description. Can’t add AD group yet…
$NewSPGroup = $site.SiteGroups.Add($SPGroupName, $site.CurrentUser, $site.CurrentUser, $SPGroupDescription)
$site.AssociatedGroups.Add($site.SiteGroups[$SPGroupName]);
$NewSPAccount = $site.SiteGroups[$SPGroupName]

#Assign the Group permission
$GroupAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($NewSPAccount)
$GroupRole = $site.RoleDefinitions[$SPGroupPermission]
$GroupAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($GroupRole)
$site.RoleAssignments.Add($GroupAssignment)

#Add the AD Group/User to the group, can’t be done during group creation when using Powershell otherwise errors so is done now.
Set-SPUser -Identity $ADGroupSPFriendly -Web $SiteCollection -Group $SPGroupName
}
$site.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: I also have 1 more question, refer to the link http://www.sharepointfire.com/2013/11/renaming-an-ad-group-in-sharepoint-2013/ .... if we click on an AD group that is already in SP we get to know its identity claim so does this code be generated automatically when the AD group is  added to SP through the script given by you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand what is your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: can you provide me the script to add an AD group to an existing SP group for a single site collection

Comment: just edited my answer with that

Comment: $ADGroupSPFriendly = $site | Get-SPUser $ADGroupName 
Get-SPUser : You must specify a valid user object or user identity.Invalid Argument error

Comment: Tried the second script from the link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133960/how-to-add-ad-group-to-sharepoint-group-using-powershell/193344#193344

Comment: did the second one work?

Comment: no, its the error mentioned : Get-SPUser : You must specify a valid user object or user identity.Invalid Argument error

Comment: that means it's not finding the ad group you specified

Comment: I am trying to add it for the first time, where will it try to look for the AD group

Comment: if the AD group is already synced with sharepoint it should find it. You can check if it is by trying to manually give this group permission in a site and see if you can find it

Comment: That is working, I can manually add the AD group to any of the SP groups...AD group is being recognized ..just that It shd be added through script to SP

Comment: check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a2e7f4e1-b6c9-4f7a-abd5-4e54976868d4/adding-ad-group-users-to-sharepoint-groups-using-powershell?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: @Anju any luck?

Comment: The script mentioned in your previous comment adds members from AD group to SP group which is not  my requirement. I just want to add an AD group eg: domain2\NewAD to any of the SP group. This domain2\NewAD  has members in it. I have the old AD grp in SP i.e domain1\OldAD  which needs to be replaced with new group. Can you suggest best possible ways to achieve this ? I was trying to add the new AD group via PS and remove the old grp via PS later. Does renaming old AD grp to new AD grp work ?

Comment: Hi Rafael, I could validate upto this step EnsureUser($ADGroupName), ensureuser returned correct values but getting error at next step i.e $ADGroupSPFriendly = $site | Get-SPUser $ADGroupName (Error: Get-SPUser : You must specify a valid user object or user identity.) For the second script from the link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133960/how-to-add-ad-group-to-sharepoint-group-using-powershell.